# Output a colon delimited file to another file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have the following example file:

```
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:adm bin daemon lp mail other root sys users
sectmp:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:users
smbnull:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:ids
sav:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:sav users
sshd:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:sshd
sys:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:sys
systemp:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:bin sys users
```

I want to create a new file with each login account that belongs to more than one group put on a separate line, such as:

```
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:adm 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:bin 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:daemon 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:lp 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:mail 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:other 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:root 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:sys 
root:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:users
sectmp:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:users
smbnull:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:ids
sav:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:sav 
sav:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:users
sshd:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:sshd
sys:server1:2014-12-12:x:Locked:sys
systemp:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:bin 
systemp:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:sys 
systemp:server1:2014-12-12:x:Open:users
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using, `awk`:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '{split ($NF, groups, " "); $NF=""; for (i in groups) {printf "%s%s\n", $0, groups[i]}}'
```

Assigning to a field (like in `$NF=""`) causes `$0` to have instances of `FS` replaced with the `OFS`, so we have to assign `:` to `OFS`. Don't expect any order in the output - the group field will be randomly output. Use a `sort` later if you need it.

Comment: Why do you say the `group` field will be randomly output? `split` stores tokens in order

Comment: @1_CR I didn't get ordered output and assumed it was due to `for (i in groups)`, not `split`

Comment: ok. `n = split ($NF, groups, " "); for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)...` should do the trick